# .htaccess – rewrite all requests to index.php except for files in certain directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It actually seems lile I found the solution, but because .htaccess und mod_rewrite are always confusing, I'm asking for verification:

I want to rewrite all traffic to the index.php, except those requests going to existing files in certain directories. Is this the correct solution? ...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !css/(.*)|js/(.*)|img/(.*)|media/(.*)
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I dropped the commonly used

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Because I don't want to have directory indexing and there are no subdirectories with an index.html or index.php, that I want to have loaded.

After all this seems like a very simple, secure and generic setup, so that I'm asking myself, why I never saw that before.

Comment: Because you would need to list all the white-listed folders like you're doing but using the wrong left-hand which should have been REQUEST_URI so instead they just check for folder existence which is a lot easier. And block it from listing directories with no index(`Options -Indexes`) inside.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have conditions right like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|js|img|media)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: @Prix: Thanks for fixing my typo :)

Comment: Had to call a L extermination team, will send you the bill later :P